# Joomla Main Menu not showing

Tags: php, joomla

I am facing an problem.Main menu is not showing on the registration page and forget password page.It is visible on rest of pages.Please help me to sought it out.

Comment: Change page layout from admin. May be...

Comment: where i find page layout?

Comment: Please try: Extensions -> Module Manager -> (select your menu module) -> Menu Assignment -> On all pages

Comment: it is already assigned to "On all pages".